# auditd not compressing logs during rotation

Tags: logrotate, audit

Audit is not compressing any logs. Perhaps this is a config issue. Could you perhaps tell me what's causing this in the below config?

```
local_events = yes
write_logs = yes
log_file = /var/log/audit/audit.log
log_group = root
log_format = RAW
flush = INCREMENTAL_ASYNC
freq = 50
max_log_file = 100
num_logs = 5
priority_boost = 4
disp_qos = lossy
dispatcher = /sbin/audispd
name_format = NONE
##name = mydomain
max_log_file_action = keep_logs
space_left = 75
space_left_action = email
action_mail_acct = root
admin_space_left = 50
admin_space_left_action = SUSPEND
disk_full_action = SUSPEND
disk_error_action = SUSPEND
use_libwrap = yes
##tcp_listen_port =
tcp_listen_queue = 5
tcp_max_per_addr = 1
##tcp_client_ports = 1024-65535
tcp_client_max_idle = 0
enable_krb5 = no
krb5_principal = auditd
##krb5_key_file = /etc/audit/audit.key
distribute_network = no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

auditd cannot compress its own logs, you need to set up logrotate for that. For more info please check:

https://bgstack15.wordpress.com/2018/02/13/logrotate-audit-log-selinux-cron-and-ansible/

or
https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/vmware_vrealize_operations_manager_6.x_sles/2018-10-11/finding/V-88747

Both are slightly outdated but you can trivially replace `service restart auditd` with `systemctl restart auditd`

---

Changes required for auditd.conf (by default it rotates files on its own which is not what we're looking for):

```
max_log_file             =  0
max_log_file_action      =  ignore
```

An example logrotate file, e.g. `/etc/logrotate.d/audit`

```
/var/log/audit/*.log {
        weekly
        missingok
        compress
        #copytruncate
        rotate 30
        minsize 100k
        maxsize 200M
        postrotate
                touch /var/log/audit/audit.log ||:
                chmod 0600 /var/log/audit/audit.log ||:
                service auditd restart
        endscript
}
```